# wp-admin automatically redirects, not able to access wordpress dashboard

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login, wordpress-admin

When I'm trying to access my WordPress dashboard like, https://www.example.com/wp-admin then it automatically redirects to

https://www.example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

What I'm suppose to do?? and when I login to this url I'm redirect to example.com/user/

I'm not able to access WordPress dashboard

[screen shot of url redirects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg1u3.png)

and when i enter username and password and try to login, it's redirect  to user page

[after login redirects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH72Z.png)

Comment: does your site has ssl

Comment: try adding to  define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false); wp-config.php file

Comment: yes it has ssl from cloudflare and it doesn't work by adding this line to wp-config.php file

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem in your `.htaccess` file. Please delete `.htaccess` file and try to login again. Then logged-in successfully.

After that, you can access your dashboard URL https://www.example.com/wp-admin.

**Note:** Now you need to change permalink from admin panel as:

```
Settings -> Permalinks
```

[image]

Change to plain and save it. After visiting then you reset it and `.htaccess` file regenerate automatically.

Comment: Yes, Please remove it with backup.

Comment: Please see this link https://www.fixrunner.com/cannot-login-wordpress-admin-area/

Comment: it doesn't work, i delete `.htaccess` file from plublic_html/.htaccess, but nothing change, even when i login it redirect to https://www.example.com/user/<USERNAME>/?redirect_to=https://www.example.com/

Comment: Okay, Have logged in and able to see adminpanel strip after loggin?

Comment: @ParthNandaniya, please do one thing as The simplest methods, I suggest you delete the wp-admin folder and wp-include folder that is present, you can remove them via the main FTP. after that, you upload files wp-admin & wp-include folder. You may be using the latest version of the Wordpress or another version you want. And try again.

Comment: i'm not able to access wp dashboard, and if i delete this 2 folder, where can i find this folder to upload it again??

Comment: @ParthNandaniya, download latest version of WordPress from https://wordpress.org/download/

Comment: **i solve it by editing database**, it's actually problem with users.

so if you have this problem too, first of all delete all the users in database and create a new admin user then try to login in wp-admin, you will redirect to dashboard

Answer (score 0):

if u have the follow in .htaccess please remove it..then ur admin will work fine

```
# ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

This has Worked Form me.

Just comment out this part of code in user.php

```
*   do_action_ref_array( 'wp_authenticate', array( &$credentials['user_login'], 

*&$credentials['user_password'] ) );

*   if ( '' === $secure_cookie )
*       $secure_cookie = is_ssl();
*/
    /**
```